# Area of target board(circular shape)

Tags: geometry, circles

I know how to find area and circumference of target boards, but I dont know why I am finding one question from new mastering mathematics for Eexcel GCSE syllabus bit weird. As the answer scheme is published by publishers and work out of this question does not match anywhere near to it. I just want to get confirm if I am doing it write.

So here is the question.
[image: paste in this image due to picture contained in it.]

When I solve it I get answer 163.35 cm(square) for red area and 157.06 cm(square) for blue area and the difference would be 376.99cm(square).

*According to answer scheme the answer is 816.81 cm(square) for red area and 439.82 cm(square) for blue area and the difference would be 6.29.*

Comment: How did you solve the question?

Comment: Using the formula for the area of an annulus $\pi(R^2-r^2)$, where $R$ is the radius of the entire figure, and $r$ is the radius of the hole, I got an answer of $732 cm^2$. Can you put a link to the markscheme and post the steps to your answer?

Comment: Hi Toby, kindly accept my apologies for replying late. Here is the link to answer scheme https://www.hoddereducation.co.uk/media/Documents/Maths/Mastering%20Mathematics%20for%20Edexcel/EdexcelGCSEMathsFoundation1_Answers_1.pdf?ext=.pdf and this question answer is on page 186  and question number 5.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the question:

The first blue area is calculated using πr²

The first red area is calculated using πr² and then subtracting (the area of the first blue area)

The second blue area is calculated using πr² and then subtracting (the area of the first blue area + the area of the first red area)

The second red area is calculated using πr² and then subtracting (the area of the first blue area + the area of the first red area + the second blue area)

Total blue area = first blue area + second blue area

Total red area = first red area + second red area

Difference = total blue area - total red area

Working out:

---

First Blue Area: π(5)² = **25π**

First Red Area: π(9)² - (25π) = 81π - (25π) = **56π**

Second Blue Area: π(14)² - (25π+56π) = 196π - (25π+56π) = **115π**

Second Red Area: π(20)² - (25π+56π+115π) = 400π - (25π+56π+115π) = **204π**

Total Red Area = **204π + 56π** = 260π = **816.814089933 cm²**

Total Blue Area = **25π + 115π** = 140π = **439.822971503 cm²**

Difference between Total Red Area and Total Blue Area=

**816.814089933 cm²** - **439.822971503 cm²** = **376.99111843 cm²**

---

Let me know if you don't understand or need more help.